# AngularJS Table Custom Search Filter Per Column

Tags: angularjs, filter, filtering

I am looking for help in creating a custom filter that will work on any table that has a search property.

So far, I can get the table to filter based on what is input into each column search bar, but I can't figure out how to implement a 'startsWith' for each column as well so that it will only find 'Florida' if you type 'Flor' or 'Fl', etc. instead of finding it when typing 'lor' or 'ida'.

I have been able to get just one column working with a custom filter, but lost on how to implement this for multiple columns.

Here is the plunkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/CE3uhZmksiepmVL2bLNF?p=preview

Script:

```
var app = angular.module("stateManagement", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", myCtrl]);

function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{
    Name: "Florida",
    Country: "USA"
  }, {
    Name: "Texas",
    Country: "USA"
  }]

  $scope.state = '';

  $scope.elements = [{
    state: "Florida"
  }, {
    state: "Texas"
  }];
}

app.filter('myfilter', function() {

  function strStartsWith(str, prefix) {
    return (str.toLowerCase() + "").indexOf(prefix.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }


  return function(items, state) {


    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if (strStartsWith(item.state, state)) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });

    return filtered;
  };

});
```

Html:

```
<body ng-app='stateManagement' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input class="form-control"
                               type="text"
                               placeholder="Search..."
                               ng-model="search.Name"/>
                    </th>
                    <th><input class="form-control"
                               type="text"
                               placeholder="Search..."
                               ng-model="search.Country"/>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:search">
                    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input ng-model="state">

        <table id="hotels">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="element in elements | myfilter:state">
                <td>{{element.state}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: Well, how does the standard filter filter do? It takes a search object as argument, looking like `{Name: 'somevalue', Country: 'someOtherValue'}`. And it compares the Name property of each element of the collection with the Name property of the search object, and the Country property of each element of the collection with the Country property of the sarch filter. You need to do the same thing, but compare using a startsWith rather than a contains.

Comment: There are numerous table/grid modules with this feature built in...why re-invent the wheel?